# загрузка и вывод фото из базы данных

Tags: php

Так у меня 2 файла add.php для upload-a а индекс для вывода. Этот код работает отлично в локальном сервере XAMPP а так в каком то сайте не выводит фото а так тексты нормально в чем проблема помогите
add.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('dbConfig.php');
    $upload_dir = 'uploads/';

    if(isset($_POST['btnSave'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $position = $_POST['position'];

        $imgName = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
        $imgTmp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];

        if(empty($name)){
            $errorMsg = 'ayble nese yaz';
        }elseif(empty($position)){
            $errorMsg = 'nese yazda blee';
        }elseif(empty($imgName)){
            $errorMsg = 'wekil sec cuwka';
        }else{
            //get image extension
            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            //allow extenstion
            $allowExt  = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
            //random new name for photo
            $userPic = time().'_'.rand(1000,9999).'.'.$imgExt;
            //check a valid image
            if(in_array($imgExt, $allowExt)){
                //check image size less than 5MB
                if($imgSize < 5000000){
                    move_uploaded_file($imgTmp ,$upload_dir.$userPic);
                }else{
                    $errorMsg = 'Image too large';
                }
            }else{
                $errorMsg = 'Please select a valid image';
            }
        }

        //check upload file not error than insert data to database
        if(!isset($errorMsg)){
            $sql = "insert into images(name, position, photo)
                    values('".$name."', '".$position."', '".$userPic."')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if($result){
                $successMsg = 'Vse boomba kimi';
                header('refresh:3;index.php');
            }else{
                $errorMsg = 'Error '.mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.file-upload {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.file-upload-btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1FB264;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #15824B;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.file-upload-btn:hover {
  background: #1AA059;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file-upload-btn:active {
  border: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.file-upload-content {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.file-upload-input {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-upload-wrap {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 4px dashed #1FB264;
  position: relative;
}

.image-dropping,
.image-upload-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #1FB264;
  border: 4px dashed #ffffff;
}

.image-title-wrap {
  padding: 0 15px 15px 15px;
  color: #222;
}

.drag-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.drag-text h3 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #15824B;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.file-upload-image {
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.remove-image {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #cd4535;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #b02818;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.remove-image:hover {
  background: #c13b2a;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove-image:active {
  border: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}</style>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Uploadimage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <h3 class="navbar-brand">Sekil soxusdur getsin</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Tep teze
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="index.php">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> &nbsp;Geri
            </a>
        </h3>
    </div>

    <?php
        if(isset($errorMsg)){       
    ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info">
                <strong><?php echo $errorMsg; ?></strong>
            </span>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>

    <?php
        if(isset($successMsg)){     
    ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info">
                <strong><?php echo $successMsg; ?> - 2 saniye doz zor olacaq</strong>
            </span>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-md-2">NEse yaz getsin</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="position" class="col-md-2">Haqqinda yaz</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="position" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="photo" class="col-md-2">Sekilin ozu bled</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="myfile">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btnSave">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>go ver
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


<div class="text"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('dbConfig.php');
    $upload_dir = 'uploads/';
    if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
        $id = $_GET['delete'];

        //select old photo name from database
        $sql = "select photo from images where id = ".$id;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $photo = $row['photo'];
            unlink($upload_dir.$photo);
            //delete record from database
            $sql = "delete from images where id=".$id;
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
                header('location:sekil.php');
            }
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.gallery picture {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.gallery img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #2590EB;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper .file-upload {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2590EB 50%, #FFFFFF 50%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.wrapper .file-upload a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper .file-upload:hover {
  background-position: 0 -100%;
  color: #2590EB;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .wrapper .file-upload {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2590EB 50%, #FFFFFF 50%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 50px;
}

}

</style>
    <title>Uploadimage</title>
        <link href="./css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <h3 class="navbar-brand">PHP upload image</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="file-upload">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<a href="add.php"> </a>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
                $sql = "select * from images";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            ?>

            <div class="gallery">

  <picture>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $upload_dir.$row['photo'] ?>"  >

  </picture>
</div>

                        <a class="btn btn-info" href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Deyiw sekli
                        </a><br>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="sekil.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" onclick="return confirm('100% sikdir elirsen?')">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>Sikdir ele
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="sekil.php?download=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" >
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>Yukle bled
                        </a>

            <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попытайтесь указать пути с использованием магической константы `__DIR__`, которая содержит путь к текущей папки

Еще возможно у php на сервере нет расширения mysqli